# GoogleMaps getLatLng Did you mean suggestion

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api

I am trying to integrate the function into a map where you can enter an address and it puts a marker on the map. But with Google Maps getLatLng if there is a slight error in the name of the address it doesn't work anymore is there a did you mean function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[API Tutorial for "Did you mean?"](http://econym.googlepages.com/didyoumean.htm)

Comment: This only applies when there are multiple results. The question is about the case when there is an error in the address and Google returns no results.

Comment: hey man i need this too. The url is no longer working. Give me some infos thanks.

Comment: The website is still available at the Internet Archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20080822102656/http://econym.googlepages.com/didyoumean.htm